# need to create a java loop with different user inputs to each loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have the following code that is displaying a parking ticket for each customer that is inputed.

I need to create a for or while loop that displays a parking ticket 9 times that allows the user to enter a different customer name, rego number and hours parked in every loop. I'm unsure how to do this.

```
package week3;

import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Week3 
{
  static final double costPerHour = 4.25;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String customerName;
    String customerNumberPlate;
    int hoursParked;
    double parkingFee; 


Scanner inText = new Scanner(System.in); //Create scanner object
Scanner inNumber = new Scanner(System.in); //Create scanner object

System.out.print("Please enter name of customer >>> "); //Prompt asking user for name
customerName = inText.nextLine(); //Declare string object

System.out.print("Please enter number plate of " + customerName +"'s vehicle >>> "); //Prompt asking for user number plate
customerNumberPlate = inText.nextLine();

System.out.print("Please enter hours customer parked >>> ");
hoursParked = inNumber.nextInt();

   if(hoursParked > 0 && hoursParked <=1) //Set boundaries 
    parkingFee = 4.25;

 else
    if (hoursParked > 1 && hoursParked <= 6) 
    parkingFee = (3.50 * hoursParked);

 else 
    parkingFee = (2.75 * hoursParked);

System.out.println("\n" + "--------Receipt--------" + "\n" 
+ "Customer: " + customerName + "\n"     
+ "Number Plate >>> " +  customerNumberPlate + "\n"
+ "Hours Parked >>> " + hoursParked + "\n"
+ "Parking Fee >>> " + parkingFee);
}
}
```

Comment: Wrap that entire block of code in a `for` loop?  (It would be cleaner -- easier to read -- if you moved the code to a separate method first and then just looped over a single method call.)

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the loop `for`, `while` or `do ... while` to get your result. In the case below, I use the loop `for`. May be you can change the type of the loop.
- You don't need two `Scanner` objects. One object is sufficient and pratical. Here, I name it `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)` and at the end of the each loop, you need to clean the actual input line with this code `input.nextLine()` (see the code below).
- When the user enters an letter in a place of a number for the customer's hours parked, the code generate an error (exception in Java). You need to see how to handle this error using `try ... catch` bloc.

**In the case of the loop while:**

```
int counter = 0;

while (counter < 9) {

  /* your actual code */

  counter++;

}
```

**Int the case of the loop do ... while:**

```
int counter = 0;

do {

  /* your actual code */

  counter++;

} while (counter < 9);
```

**In the case of the loop for:**
*(Here, the code is more complete)*

```
package week3;
import java.util.Scanner; 
 public class Week3 
{
  static final double costPerHour = 4.25;

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    String customerName;
    String customerNumberPlate;
    int hoursParked;
    double parkingFee; 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        System.out.print("Please enter name of customer >>> "); //Prompt asking user for name
        customerName = input.nextLine(); //Declare string object

        System.out.print("Please enter number plate of " + customerName +"'s vehicle >>> "); //Prompt asking for user number plate
        customerNumberPlate = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter hours customer parked >>> ");
        hoursParked = input.nextInt();

        if(hoursParked > 0 && hoursParked <=1) //Set boundaries 
            parkingFee = 4.25;

         else
            if (hoursParked > 1 && hoursParked <= 6) 
            parkingFee = (3.50 * hoursParked);

         else 
            parkingFee = (2.75 * hoursParked);

        System.out.println("\n" + "--------Receipt--------" + "\n" 
        + "Customer: " + customerName + "\n"     
        + "Number Plate >>> " +  customerNumberPlate + "\n"
        + "Hours Parked >>> " + hoursParked + "\n"
        + "Parking Fee >>> " + parkingFee);

        System.out.println("");

        input.nextLine(); // important: to clean the actual line

    }

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the for loop also and got the same result as you

Comment: @E.Allen: If it helps you, you should accept the answer to say that your question is resolved.